# StanfordNLP POS giving mixed results

Tags: java, stanford-nlp, part-of-speech

I was testing Stanford NLP POS Tagger, I am getting mixed results.

```
SOP(StanfordNLP.getInstance().getPOSMap("WHEAT flour(whole)".toLowerCase()));
SOP(StanfordNLP.getInstance().getPOSMap("Whole wheat flour".toLowerCase()));
```

Gives me the following output

```
{NN=[wheat, flour, whole]}
{JJ=[whole], NN=[wheat, flour]}
```

How can I deal with problems like these? Its actually the same words rearranged.

**EDIT**

Maybe, I should explain the problem.

I want to compare 2 sentences. My approach is perform POS on both string and then compare and score individually Nouns/Adjectives/Verbs from both strings.

But because of fuzzy tagging (as also reffered to by @Elliott) based on order of words, my ranking fails in some cases. Can someone suggest a workaround?

Is there a classification statistics which gives the probability of a Noun classified as Adjective or Verb etc, that i can use in my scoring algo to provide weights?

thanks
Chahat

Answer (score 0):

POS taggers always give mixed results; the POS tagging is contextual since a word can be a noun, adjective, or verb in different contexts. The [AI component](http://nlp.stanford.edu/~manning/papers/tagging.pdf) of POS tagging decides how to tag words based on their order in the sentence.

Comment: Thanks @Elliott, maybe I wasn't clear with my problem earlier.

Answer (score -2):

Stanford POS Tagger is pretty good. If however you want to easily see side by side comparisons with standard NLTK and other quality tagger called Senna you could try this:
https://github.com/StealthyK/TaggerTimer

Comment: Please provide more details : on Stackoverflow links should be used as references, your question should answer by itself.

Comment: There's too much code to paste. The link is to code that will let the OP compare different POS taggers with MP threading to compare results on any range of text inputs.